# Building snap parts from subdirectories using different plugins

Tags: ubuntu-core, snap

I'm trying to create a snap for one of our projects. The project repository contains two directories and I want to build one with `go` plugin and the other with `nodejs` plugin. I tried building them as separate parts and using `source-subdir` but it did not work as I expected. So my question is how do I tell plugin to step into a directory before starting a build?

We normally build this project using docker `go` and `node` containers or using a build machine with build tools pre-installed. It has a working `Makefile` for this but I'm trying to avoid managing build dependencies externally (either on go/nodejs or docker) and use go/nodejs tools provided by snap craft plugins.

**Update:**

Here is a sketch of project structure:

```
./go-module-1/...
./go-module-2/...
./go-module-3/...
./go-module-main/static/package.json
./go-module-main/static/...
./go-module-main/main.go
./go-module-main/...
./pkg-build.sh
./...
```

So, the normal process for building this project would be:

```
(cd go-module-main && go build .)
(cd go-module-main/static && npm run build)
./pkg-build.sh
```

The `go` portion of project exposes restful API and `nodejs` part is actually only used for compiling client side app (Angular/SASS/bower/gulp).

Comment: Have you tried simply providing a different `source` for each plugin?

Comment: @Kyle, yes I have, but I still need to run a build from subdirectory.

Comment: In that case, how did `source-subdir` not work the way you expected?

Comment: `source-subdir` only copies the subdirectory into `install` location (preserving its path), so I still need to step inside. I also experimented with `organize` but it seem does not apply at this stage.

Comment: It would be useful to see an example we can duplicate, if possible.

Comment: @Kyle, I've just updated my question with project directory structure.